# Getting url of submitted form using jquery

Tags: jquery, url

Using Rails, I am submitting a form that generates a new url each time the form is submitted. How can I catch the url of the new form? I tried something like the following but can't get it to work

```
$('#addSyn').click(function(ev){
   url = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#expURL').text(url);
});
```

HTML/Rails

```
<section style="width:45%; right:0; position:absolute;">

<%= form_for @exp, remote: true, :id => 'EditForm' do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :Syn %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :syn %><br>

  <%= f.label :Exp %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :exp %><br>

  <%= f.submit "Add Syn", :id=>"addSyn" %>
<% end %>

<div id="ExpURL">

</div>

</section>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the "href" but not "action"?

Comment: Does the server do a redirect to send the browser to a new response url each time?  If so, that probably can not be handled from a Javascript because that Javascript has been unloaded. Maybe with an Iframe if it doesn't violate same origin policy.

Comment: @Teddy I tried "action" instead of "href" but still nothing.

Comment: @Paul - I am using rails and I inserted a statement "remote: true". Without it it does a redirect, with that statement it listens to the jquery click and  does not do a redirect.

Comment: give your html like structure

Comment: <%= f.submit "Add Syn", :id=>"addSyn" %>  in this href attribute not appear

Comment: I'm not a rails person, maybe someone else can help.

Comment: What do you mean Rituraj? I don't follow.

Comment: open your rendered code in browser and check the form id is same as `addSyn` as you are using

Comment: Please post the client side html

Answer (score 1):

You only get `#addSyn` using `$(this)` inside `$('#addSyn').click`. And the case seems wrong(if it's not a typo), it should be `#ExpURL`.

Try:

```
$('#EditForm').on('submit', function(){
  url = $(this).attr('action');
  $('#ExpURL').text(url);
});
```

Also you can use `prop` instead of `attr`.

Comment: I tried submit instead of click but when I try that then event random text such as .text('foobar') doesn't display. Ignore the casing. That was a typo